# Jenkins pipeline - start pod with image built in previous stage in a different pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins deployed on a kubernetes cluster A, and that can spawn pods in the same cluster A. My workflow is the following

- Start a pod with an image designed to build a docker image. This image will be built with a deterministic tag `example/appname:${GIT_COMMIT}`
- After the image was build in the previous pod, start a new pod with the image from the previous build (`example/appname:${GIT_COMMIT}`), and run multiple test tools

Currently I am successfully making a build with

```
podTemplate(yaml: """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: aws-dockerizer
    image: example/aws-dockerizer:0.1.7
    command: ['cat']
    tty: true
    volumeMounts:
    - name: dockersock
      mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
  volumes:
  - name: dockersock
    hostPath:
      path: /var/run/docker.sock
""") {
  node(POD_LABEL) {

    stage('Clone') {
      git url: 'https://github.com/example/my-app/', branch: '${build_branch_name}', credentialsId: 'github-app'

      container('aws-dockerizer') {
        stage('Build and deploy') {
          withAWS(credentials: 'aws-credentials', region: 'eu-central-1') {
            sh '''#!/usr/bin/env bash
              git config --global --add safe.directory ${WORKSPACE}
              scripts/build_and_push_docker_image_to_aws.sh
            '''
          }
        }
      }
    }  

  }
}
```

I'd like to add the following stage to my pipeline. Note that the new pod `"experience-${GIT_COMMIT}"` CANNOT be started because he image is not available until the previous step is complete.

```
podTemplate(
  label: "experience-${GIT_COMMIT}"
  yaml: """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: experience
    image: example.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/example/appname:${GIT_COMMIT}
    command: ['cat']
    tty: true
""") 

  stage('Run tests') {
    node("experience-${GIT_COMMIT}") {
      stage('Run tests') {
        container('experience') {
          stage('Run Rspec') {
            sh 'bundle exec rspec'
          }
          post {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea if this is possible ? What's the DSL / concepts I need to use ? How do I "merge" the two pieces of code to achieve what I want ?

I've tried to play around a bit, but when I declare both pod templates at the beginning, it hangs the job until the 2nd pod is ready, which it never will be...

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use another yaml to declare the new container to be used in a stage.

I've a pipeline that runs on a virtual machine but uses a container to run just one stage and call `kustomize` and it works, so I guess you can do the same with two containers.

Try something like this:

```js
pipeline
  agent {
    kubernetes {
     yaml """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
    imagePullSecrets:
    - regcred 
    containers:
    - name: jnlp
      image: jenkins/inbound-agent:4.10-3-alpine-jdk11
    ...
"""
  }
  stages {
    stage('A') {
      steps {
        // Runs on previously declared container  
      }
    }
    stage('Kustomize') {
      agent {
        kubernetes {
          yaml """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
...
"""
        }
      }
      steps {
        // Runs on the second container
      }
```